# Installing firebase with Cocoapods

Tags: objective-c, macos, firebase, cocoapods

I'm new using cocoapods and I still don't understand it very well. I need to use firebase in my app, but I'm having problems with it. 
I used this to prepare cocoapods on my mac:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

And then another time to update it:

```
$ [sudo] gem install cocoapods
```

And i didn't had any problem. Now I want to add the firebase library and I don't know how. I go to firebase in the cocoapods page ([here it is](https://cocoapods.org/?q=firebase)) and the only thing it says:
INSTALLATION:

```
pod 'Firebase'
```

When I use this on the terminal it says: [!] Unknown command: `Firebase`

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I have to download something, don't know.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this into PodFile
`pod 'Firebase'`

Run this command in that file terminal.
`pod install`

Add import file to your .swift
`import Firebase`

Answer (score 13):

You need to add the `pod 'Firebase'` line to a file named `Podfile` at the root of your project. Then you need to run the command: `pod install` which will read the file and install the listed pods.